# Probability that the lifetime of $6th$ phone to die is $2.5$ years

Tags: probability

Is this question not geometric? Why does it matter that you bought $10$ phones? Also, I only calculate the probability that $6$th phone to die has a lifetime greater than or equal to $2.5$ years: how do I calculate the probability that its lifetime is *exactly* $2.5$ years?

**Question**

Suppose the lifetime of a cellphone is modeled (in years) by $exp$ ~  $(0.25)$ and you buy $10$ such phones. What is the probability that the lifetime of the $6$th phone to die is $2.5$ years?

**Answer**

$P(X_i \geq 2.5) = 1 - (1 - e^{-2.5/4}) = .5353$

Using the geometric distribution, our answer is $(1-.5353)^5(.5353) = 0.0116$

Comment: Well, if you had a million phones then quite a few of them would die fast, so the answer would be near $0$ (that's why the $10$ phones matter).   And, since the distributions are continuous, the probability that the answer is $\textit {exactly}$ $2.5$ is $0$.

Comment: Isn't it $\binom{10}{5}(1-.5353)^5\cdot.5353^5$?  There are $\binom{10}5$ ways to choose the phones that die in the first $2.5$ years, etc.